# How to resize a video in slider revolution 5.4 for mobile view?

Tags: css, wordpress

I've set a background video on [this website](http://production.duzzdownsan.net/) with slider revolution on wordpress. All works fine except on the smartphone where the video resizes but still gets cropped off on the right and left side. (Btw. this will only happen on an actual smartphone but not if you inspect the site in responsive mode on Google Chrome)

I haven't found a way to make the video smaller for mobile within slider revolution so I'm looking for a custom css option to do it manually. The responsive options within slider revolution only apply to layers but not to video backgrounds.

Is there a way to give the video I guess a minimum width (?) so that the text animation in the video is fully visible on mobile? Which container should I point to with the custom CSS?

Comment: The element width must exceeding the screen size, hence you must first check and dind the element due to which the video section is not appearing properly and set it max-widrh to 100%. Thus might be fixed your problem.

Comment: This is a very specific question about a specific plugin for Wordpress so you might bot get the expertise you need here. Have you tried the plugin developer or their support page on wordpress.org? You might get more help on a WP-related forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't exactly solve this how I wanted. In this specific case with slider revolution I didn't use the background function but created a layer with the video. I then turned off "Force Cover" and increased the size on the text in the video to fill out the mobile screen.